# prevent javascript executing \n

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to prevent javascript in executing \n from string.

I have string which contains \n (i.e. "`ksqOOEe+sqQwexx12lMf31V\nLqW23ds`"). This is encrypted string and I have to handle it in Javascript. Problem is that JS break it into two rowns, than browser register Illegal operation. I don't want to escape it with other special characters because it is encrypted string and I have to use decryption process for data reconstruction in next steps.

Comment: Javascript wouldn't parse out that `\n` unless you were eval() or otherwise executing the line - how is this string getting sent to JS?

Comment: no I can't... As I said I need to do decryption operation on that string later in process flow...

Comment: @MarcB I call web service with Ajax request, and than just put it into element ($.html("<div id="xx" data-id="'+ajaxResponse.encrypted+'">'+ajaxResponse.name+'</div>");

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that this encrypted string won't contain `"` or `'` characters, you'll have to escape it, or set the data-id separately so you're not passing the raw string through jquery's HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the slash so it doesn't see it as an escape sequence. Doing this will tell javascript that it's a literal slash, not store two slashes in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using web service and generate encrypted string on Java side, I used URLEncoder to encode it before returning it to the client. Than on next request which contains the same encoded string, I decode it with URLDecoder and than with base64 decoder... It works, and thanks everyone for help :)